# Deleting forum posts

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have a table with the following fields: wall_posts, group_id, id, and user_id.

Wall_posts is user entries, group_id is imported from another table and is just a unique group id, id is just a simple counter, and user_id gets the user id from the session.

My code gets rid of all the wall_posts if you press the delete button by comparing the user id to the user in session. I'm trying to find a way to delete individual posts and not all the posts by the user.

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $current_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_posts");
    while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $user_id['user_id'];
    }
    if ($current_user == $id) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE $current_user = $id") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

How can I bound the delete button to individual posts instead of deleting all the posts made by the user currently in session?

Comment: You should delete from the `wall_posts` table. Where the wall_posts are ?

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query above doesn't make sense - the `WHERE` statement should be in the form `WHERE column_name = value`.

Assuming `id` is the primary key for group_posts, as you're displaying posts, create a link for each post created by the author, e.g. `<a href="delete.php?delete=3">Delete This Post</a>` for post with `id` 3. Then you'd do a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE id = postIdValueHere
```

Using the code pattern you have above:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] > 0) {
$current_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$post_id = (int) $_POST['delete'];

if ($current_user == $id) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE id = $post_id AND user_id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

That query ensures that only posts with a given ID, created by the current author, can be deleted.

Does that answer your question?

Once you get more comfortable with SQL, you might also want to look into using prepared statements with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). That will help your code clean and secure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your delete buttons are simple links. Your links must contain all the information to delete a post. One way would be to pass a post id as a GET variable (e.g. link="myurl.com/posts/delete?id=#").

Your script would then at first make sure the current user is allowed to delete the post. For example:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$post_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
if(canDelete($user_id, $post_id))
{
    // assuming post_id is unique for every post
    $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE id = %d", $post_id);
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Of course, you'd have to implement `canDelete($user_id)` yourself.

By the way, `"DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE $current_user = $id"` always deletes every record in your table. At first you're comparing if `$current_user` equals `$id` and if they do happen to be equal, your query would look something like `WHERE 1 = 1`. I think you mean `"DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE user_id = '$id'"`

**EDIT**: It seems you want to use ajax for deleting your posts. I recommend using jQuery or any other proper javascript framework as it saves you time. Here is a link from the jQuery documentation describing [how to make an ajax call to the server](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375356/ajax-delete-using-jquery) to help you understand better.

Comment: canDelete() would probably need two parameters, since you'd need to be able to tell if a specific post is editable by a given user. Also, you don't need to quote integer values in SQL queries. (It just converts it to an int internally, so it works, but it's a tiny bit slower as a result.)

Comment: This just deletes the newest posts. For example if I click on the delete button on a post with id=10 and the last post has an id=12. It just deletes the post with the id=12 and then pressing the delete button again results in deleting the post with id=11 and so on

Comment: I believe that the problem is that all the events are bound to the same delete button.

Comment: The query deletes any row you want it to. Remember to pass the post id somewhere in the link, e.g. 'posts/delete/?id=5' and then retrieving it server-side.

Could you please be more specific in how exactly have you implemented it right now?

Comment: Yes. Your solution requires another php page for the delete function to produce the url and for the $_GET function to work. I dont want to have a separate page for my delete function. A good example of it would be how you delete a news feed or a comment on your facebook page.

Comment: Not necessarily. The delete button link would be generated during the initial request for the server to display the post(s). Why would it need to make another request?

If you want to delete a post without making a round-trip to the server altogether, you should have mentioned it. In that case you'd have to use javascript to make an ajax call to request the server to delete the post. After that just remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with javascript. I just cant find any tutorials on this specific topic. Do you know of any?